# Accessing a cell in the GridView of a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

If I have a grid view within a listview and this grid view has definitions for 3 columns.
for each cell in the grid is a textbox, if I want to access a specific "cell" in the gridview, how do I go about doing it? I am accessing it from the C# side.

Comment: when you say "access a specific "cell"", do you mean its value or to highlight it e.g. so that it shows as selected?

Comment: @ChrisBD yup, I cant access the specific cell at all to highlight it as selected from another event. I can only access the element in which the cell is in using the visual tree helper, but it always returns me the first object in my observable collection, which is not i want.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to manipulate the cells directly; although it is possible, it's difficult and counter-intuitive. You should manipulate the bound objects instead.